# Why I can't handle the content of this infowindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/jYX2t/3/) :

## HTML

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="mappa-eventi" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>

<div id="mappa-infowindow" style="display:none;">
    <div class="mappa-infobox" style="background-color:#ffffff; width:300px; height:100px;">
        <a class="punto-leggi" href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

## jQuery/JS :

```
var map;
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(45.930976, 10.639744);

$(".punto-leggi").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Clicked");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoom: 8,
        center: location,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mappa-eventi"), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map                
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: $('#mappa-infowindow').html()
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });  
});
```

I click on the marker! Than, clicking on "LINK", it should show to me the alert. In fact it doesnt works. But, if I add this :

```
$(".punto-leggi").click();
```

at the end of document ready, it gets the "click". And the handler is called.

Why this behaviour? And how can I fix it?

Comment: why are you binding the onclick for ".punto-leggi" outside of document.ready()? put that inside!

Comment: Also tried that! It doesnt works, anyway...

Comment: i didn't expect that to fix it, but you should always bind event handlers in document.ready() (UNLESS your javascript code is at the bottom of your page...if it's in the <head>, the DOM hasn't loaded and the elements won't be found). if things are being added dynamically, you can't use simple .click() to bind, you need to use .live()/.delegate() but more recently .on()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click-handler isn't attached to the link in the `InfoWindow`. You will have to delegate the `click` with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(function() {
    // ...
    $("#mappa-eventi").on("click", ".punto-leggi", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        alert("foo");
    });
});
```

Edit: Changed `document` to `#mappa-eventi` as suggested by ianpgall

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYX2t/7/)

Comment: i wouldn't use document, but this should fix it. i'd use something closer to the container of the links...

Comment: It seems to works! But why putting `$(".punto-leggi").click();` it fire my original handler? It is the same approch :O

Comment: And, with your theory, delegate/live they should works! In fact they doesnt :O

Comment: @ianpgall You're right. I've changed it to the maps-container.

Comment: @markzzz You're attaching the delegate to the wrong element. google just uses the html of the `.mappa-infobox` element. Delegate the handler to the map-container `#mappa-eventi` and delegate() will also work.

Comment: You are right! The dubt keep solid : why my handler with `$(".punto-leggi").click();` at the end of document.ready function works :O It is like click the link...

Comment: @markzzz [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) removes the event handler from the elements. When creating the `InfoWindow` the `content` used has no handlers attached. You're `$(...).click` at the end of the `ready` handler just fires the event of the source element where the handler is properly attached.

Comment: "just fires the event of the source element where the handler is properly attached" but if no handler are attached (due to the html()) how can fire it? :O

Comment: Have a look at your code... Have a look at the source code of jQuery... When you're creating the `InfoWindow` you pass it a copy of the content in the `#mappa-infowindow`. This content has no event handler attached. When you're `$(...).click()` you click the link in the `#mappa-infowindow` which has still the event handlers attached.

Comment: Well...you are right! In fact there are two copy... and I call once ;) Thank you